# Finite second moment implies convergence

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $X$ be a martingale such that $\sup _{n>0} \mathbb{E} [X^2] < \infty$. Show that $X_n$ converges to a random variable in probability and also in $L^2$.

I've played around with trying to get convergence in probability but Im not really sure why it would converge or what to. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. $L^2$-convergence implies convergence in probability, and therefore it enough to show that $X_n$ converges in $L^2$.
2. $L^2$ is a complete space and therefore it suffices to prove that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an $L^2$-Cauchy sequence, i.e. $$\|X_n-X_m\|_{L^2}^2 = \mathbb{E}((X_n-X_m)^2)  \to 0 \quad \text{as $n,m \to \infty$}.\tag{1}$$
3. Check (or recall) that $X^2$ is a submartingale, and conclude that $$M := \sup_{n \geq 1} \|X_n\|_{L^2}^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n^2).$$ In particular, $(\mathbb{E}(X_n^2))_{n \geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
4. Use the martingale property to show that $$\mathbb{E}((X_n-X_m)^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_n^2)-\mathbb{E}(X_m^2) \quad \text{for all $m \leq n$}.$$ Hint: Write $$\mathbb{E}((X_n-X_m)^2) = \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \mathbb{E}((X_n-X_m)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_m) \bigg]$$ and expand the square.
5. Conclude from step 3 and 4 that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an $L^2$-Cauchy sequence.